# expand and populate numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the easiest way to expand and populate a python numpy array? Initially the numpy array is:

> [[1,3], [1,2], [1,5]]

after expanding, the array should be:

> [[1,3,9,27], [1,2,4,8], [1,5,25,125]]

the newly added column is the squared and cubed value of the 2nd column.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Slice the second column keeping the dimensions with `a[:,[1]]`, perform the power operations leveraging [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/user/basics.broadcasting.html) with `**[2,3]` , because we had kept the dimensions and then stack the output as new columns with `np.c_` (one of many ways to stack).

Hence, the implementation -

```
np.c_[a,a[:,[1]]**[2,3]]
```

Sample output -

```
In [902]: np.c_[a,a[:,[1]]**[2,3]]
Out[902]: 
array([[  1,   3,   9,  27],
       [  1,   2,   4,   8],
       [  1,   5,  25, 125]])
```

Comment: you are the best!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to skip over the 1 in each row, and then use broadcasting to form the desired cartesian product.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[1,3], [1,2], [1,5]])
b = a[:, 1:] ** np.arange(4)
print(b)
```

**output**

```
[[  1   3   9  27]
 [  1   2   4   8]
 [  1   5  25 125]]
```